# Float on the <p> now working like float only if I applied it to img

Tags: html, css

In the next code if you use float left or right for the image works fine, but if you use for the `<p>` I don't know why but is not working. 
I thought that float was the same for both if you applied float left and don't do a clear both will change the overflow but here it does not do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    p {
      float: right;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>In the paragraph below, we have added an image with style <b>float:right</b>.
The result is that the image will float to the right in the paragraph.

This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

    </p>
    <img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your query briefly?

Comment: *In the paragraph below, we have added an image with style <b>float:right</b>* — No, you haven't.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what behaviour you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p` is a block-level element. Being a block, it has 100% width by default. The `img`, on the other hand, is an inline element, and has some arbitrary width (which happens to be less than 100% in this case). This less-than-100%-width enables the img to float to the left/right of a block-level element such as the `p`.

If you were to give a width to the `p`, it will suddenly be able to float:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>In the paragraph below, we have added an image with style <b>float:right</b>. The result is that the image will float to the right in the paragraph.

This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

</p>
<img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ty was the width that of a p is 100% that is why with img worked, solved ty!

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the browser that the `img` tag comes *after* the `p` element.

Put the `img` tag *inside* the `p` tag at the start, and you should get what you're looking for.

[Link to Example](https://codepen.io/DeathCamel57/pen/dZeOYY)

Also, your code has the *`p`* element floating to the right according to the CSS.